# SMTP: overwriting "From" field makes the email go to spam on port 465, but not on 25

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, spam

I use a SMTP mail server to send mails from my application; the "From" field gets overwritten, so it's not equal to the real sender (ie the address that actually sends the mail). When the application connects to the mail server on port 25, everything is fine and the "From" field overwriting causes no issues. If I use the port 465 instead (with ssl), changing the "From" field causes the mail to go to spam on all mail clients. I guess this is normal in order to avoid spoofing, so my question is why it didn't happen before on port 25.

I can't use port 25 anymore since my new ISP blocks outgoing traffic on that port; currently, I'm using port 465 with the real sender in "From" (a "no-reply" address) and setting the address I need in the "ReplyTo" field only.

Are there some additional security checks that get triggered on port 465 only (maybe due to ssl)? Is there a standard way to avoid them?

Comment: This is 100% server dependent. The act of changing from 25 -> 465 on the same server *shouldn't* change anything, unless the server changes how it accepts/signs the mail.  SSL in this case is only used at the transport layer, and shouldn't effect mail content.  Are you using SMTP auth? Does the from address have SPF records published? Does the sending mail server support DKIM? Is the mail signed.  Is it possible that the Mail server got on a blacklist and the change from 25->465 is bad timing?

Comment: Thanks Doon for the insights. Auth is on in both cases; no SPF records published for any address; on the mail server DKIM is on (SPF is off), should I try to disable it? I don't think it's blacklisted, since using port 25 again works fine. One difference is the server on which the application runs, since I can't test connecting to 25 from the new one. Can the mail be modified by some configuration on that server (the application code is of course the same)?

Comment: So the application is running on a new server (ISP). This ISP blocks outbound 25, so you need to use 465 with your outbound relay server? Do you have access to the headers from a message that is getting marked as spam? Is there any indication of why the receiving server is marking it as spam. Does your application send the mail directly or does it use an MTA on the server to send the mail?  I wonder if the new IP your server is running on has bad reputation and receiving sites are doing lookups further down the received path.